# No column in target database, but getting "The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur"

Tags: dacpac, sqlproj

I had been getting the error when publishing a SQL project.

I was testing on a database made from the production schema with some test data.

When I looked at the error from the Data Tools Operations tab in Visual Studio, I saw this:

```
/*
The column [dbo].[MyTableName].[UnexpectedColumnName] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
*/
IF EXISTS (select top 1 1 from [dbo].[MyTableName])
    RAISERROR (N'Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.', 16, 127) WITH NOWAIT
GO
```

However, the `UnexpectedColumnName` column name has not been in that table for quite a long time.

The question was how why that SQL was being generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the refactor log had something really old in it. I asked the publish step to generate the script rather than publish immediately and searched for `UnexpectedColumnName`:

```
GO
PRINT N'The following operation was generated from a refactoring log file 69ad6ffa-f53e-4302-a9af-a6f6907e4eec, 5879552a-9f2d-439c-82c8-352bbee08bb2';
PRINT N'Rename [dbo].[MyTableName].[ArbitraryRealColumnName] to UnexpectedColumnName';

GO
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'[dbo].[MyTableName].[ArbitraryRealColumnName]', @newname = N'UnexpectedColumnName', @objtype = N'COLUMN';
```

I then looked into the refactoring log and saw this matching the GUID:

```
  <Operation Name="Rename Refactor" Key="5879552a-9f2d-439c-82c8-352bbee08bb2" ChangeDateTime="02/13/2020 20:07:08">
    <Property Name="ElementName" Value="[dbo].[MyTableName].[NotSureWhatThisIs]" />
    <Property Name="ElementType" Value="SqlSimpleColumn" />
    <Property Name="ParentElementName" Value="[dbo].[MyTableName]" />
    <Property Name="ParentElementType" Value="SqlTable" />
    <Property Name="NewName" Value="UnexpectedColumnName" />
  </Operation>
```

Because we don't use those refactoring log features, I just deleted the whole refactoring log, and everything worked. I'd imagine you could also just delete the errant rename.